# How to extract rows if vector is present in two columns of a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe

```
df <- structure(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "A", "D", "E", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"), .Dim = 4:3, .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("A1", "B1", "C1"
)))
```

I want to see if vector `x <- c("A", "B", "D", "E")` is present in both columns A1 and B1, of `df`, then I want to extract those rows (Notice E is not present in column A1, so exclude that row). So, the expected result should be:

`df[1:3,]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over the `matrix` with columns selected 'A1', 'B1', check if `all` values of 'x' are `%in%` those column and wrap with `all`

```
all(apply(df[, 1:2], 2, function(y) all(x %in% y)))
#[1] FALSE
```

---

In order to subset the rows

```
df[rowSums(apply(df[, 1:2], 2, function(y) y %in% x)) == 2,]
#      A1  B1  C1 
#[1,] "A" "B" "3"
#[2,] "B" "A" "4"
#[3,] "D" "E" "6"
```

Comment: It only gives T or F, how do I get the actual rows?